# Illustrating mathematics

Tags: software-recommendation

What options do I have to draw mathematical objects?

I know I can use Inkscape to draw parametric curves, but what about polygons? Or, vector fields?

Whenever I Google this, I find things like tons of software that generate fractals or Geogebra. So, I cannot find what I am actually looking for.

One option, of course, is to draw it like one would draw anything else in Illustrator or Inkscape. Is there any other, more efficient, option?

Comment: I think you should post a pencil drawing of what mathematics you are thinking of. ANY vector file is a mathematical representation, inclusive a font. But i do not tknow if you are thinking of revolution solids, or things like this: http://functionspace.com/topic/360/What-are-the-funniest-beautiful-graph-s-equations-. There is an aditional issue. Not every program could calculate the curve for you, so you basicly need to copy the shape.

Comment: Well, I did write polygons and vector fields. However, my question is more general since my website is going to be about a lot of different things (all mathematical). I want to know what software/methods are available.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use a vector drawing program. Corel, Ilustrator, Inkscape. Then you can make the graphs as the style you like.

Comment: Are you asking about mathematical symbols, or visualizing mathematical equations? My hunch is the latter and would suggest you investigate JS visualization libraries geared to this. Here's one: http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/

Comment: Well, not just equations. How about polygons? Or, other constructible geometric shapes? Is there a Geogebra for design?

I am not asking about mathematical symbols. There are more than enough fonts available to write greek letters or the integral sign.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want to approach things. I find that by far the best option is **Mathematica**. Although, Mathematica is expensive, for commercial use, it is quite affordable otherwise. Mathematica is however not everybody's cup of tea. If you can not afford Mathematica consider, *Python* + numpy, scipy, sympy combo, or *octave* if you can afford it Matlab would be fine too.

[image: Vector stream field]

**Image 1** A vector streamfield quickly generated in Mathematica, and touched up in Illustrator.

Nothing says you can not use several applications together. Any of the above + illustrator makes a formidable tool set.

Drawing the field manually is not out of the question. Although you could easily script the field generation. I have made a similar, but crude, parametric curve drawing routine as you find in inkscape. You can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/joojaa/jooillustratorscripts/src).  It wouldn't take much work to convert it to draw vector fields if your point distribution is known.

#### Rescources:

- examples of vector fields in [Mathematica](http://www.demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=vector%20field)